# should i require two sets of graphics for supporting interface orientation?

Tags: iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

Should i remove the graphics in landscape mode and then add the graphics in potrait mode and the vice versa..is it done the same way?? or else is there are some other way...

My graphics is not in plain background so any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please be more clear? I'm not getting your Question.Maybe I can help you if you put Q in more simpler language.

Comment: Which kind of Graphics you're trying to mention?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the same UIImageView objects as containers for your graphics, resize them as appropriate on orientation change, and change their content image if necessary (if a simple stretching or cropping of your images as accomplished by the different UIViewContentMode options isn't satisfactory).

Comment: i am not asking about the images that i use for displaying content, but the actual background itself..if i am using an ipad 1024*768, can i use the same bg for 768 * 1024?

Comment: You can but the content will be stretched or cropped.